# How many context provider we should have in the page React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is it good to have the context provider according to the page wise.
For example Dashboard have one Provider called Dashboard Provider And test have another provider called Test Provider.
Or it is good to have single big provider for all the different page.

Comment: A good measure of thumb would be to life up the Provider only to that level, whose children are direct / indirect consumers of it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React docs for context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context).

> Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by
> many components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly
> because it makes component reuse more difficult.
>
> **If you only want to avoid passing some props through many levels**,
> **component composition is often a simpler solution than context**.

Comment: Yeah I got it. I want is using the context according to page is in practice. Loading only if user visit the page at a time.

Comment: Sorry, don't want to come across as preachy, just want to warn people that overuse of context can lead to some hard to follow code.  I am guilty of this, when I discover a hammer, everything looks like a nail for a while, later I realize they aren't all nails.